# Can I replace h:commandLink with h:link

Tags: jsf

I'm creating a mobi-site using jsf. I got right to the end and found that more primitive phone browsers can't handle the javascript that commandLink creates. Is it possible to circumvent this with h:link or do you have any other suggestion as to how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h:commandLink>` generates a HTML `<a>` element with JS code in `onclick` to submit a POST form.

If your functional requirement is to submit a form with some data, then better use `<h:commandButton>`, it doesn't generate JS code.

If your functional requirement is to navigate to other page, then you should definitely use `<h:link>`, or `<h:outputLink>`, or just plain HTML `<a>`.